# Promtail deployment config on EC2: error in DescribeInstances

Tags: amazon-ec2, grafana-loki, promtail

I'm just configuring promtail and testing it out on my EC2 instance, running this

`./promtail-linux-amd64 -config.file=./ec2-promtail.yaml --dry-run`

I get the following error

`<ErrorResponse “http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/200. Sender. InvalidAction. <|Message>Could not find operation DescribeInstances for version 2. . | 2bbe..caused by: expected element type but have ”`

I'm checking if my config is wrong and if anyone has faced this issue.

I'm configuring Promtail on an AML Linux 2 Instance. My instance has no internet connection (security reasons) so I am using STS endpoint in my region to authenticate the role.

Promtail version: 2.7.1

AWS Role: Has `DescribeInstance`, `DescribeAvailabilityZone` permissions

The following is my `ec2_sd_config`

```
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 0

clients:
  - url: https://loki.dev.fdp.internal/loki/api/v1/push

positions:
  filename: /opt/promtail/positions.yaml

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: ec2-logs
    ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: ap-southeast-1
        role_arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/promtail_role
        endpoint: sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com # define to use regional endpoint instead of the default global
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Name]
        target_label: name
        action: replace
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_instance_id]
        target_label: instance
        action: replace
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_availability_zone]
        target_label: zone
        action: replace
      - action: replace
        replacement: /var/log/**.log
        target_label: __path__
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_private_dns_name]
        regex: "(.*)"
        target_label: __host__
```